# The thunkAPI.getState method does not correctly infer the state type

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Code here:

`users.slice.ts`:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const userAPI = {
  async fetchById(userId: string) {
    return { data: { id: userId, name: 'teresa teng' } };
  },
};

export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<User, string>(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId);
    return response.data;
  },
  {
    condition: (userId, { getState }) => {
      const { users } = getState();
      const { fetchStatus } = users[userId];
      if (fetchStatus === 'loading') {
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
);

interface User {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}

interface UsersSliceState {
  [id: string]: { fetchStatus: 'idle' | 'loading'; data: User };
}

const usersSliceState: UsersSliceState = {
  1: {
    fetchStatus: 'idle',
    data: { name: '', id: '' },
  },
};

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: usersSliceState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
    });
  },
});

export default usersSlice.reducer;
```

`store.ts`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import usersSliceReducer from './users.slice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: usersSliceReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { store } from './store';
import { fetchUserById } from './users.slice';

store.dispatch(fetchUserById('1'));
```

TSC throws an error when I call `getState()` method and deconstruct the `users` state slice inside `condition` function

> Property 'users' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

The `RootState` type inferred is:

```
type RootState = {
    users: UsersSliceState;
}
```

How should I make this type correctly? If I import the `RootState` type and type cast the return value of `getState()`, will it cause circular references?

package versions:

```json
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the `state` in [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk) to be `RootState`, where `state` is part of the optional fields for defining `thunkApi` field types.

```
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<
 User,
 string, 
 { state: RootState}
>(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId);
    return response.data;
  },
  {
    condition: (userId, { getState }) => {
      const { users } = getState();
      const { fetchStatus } = users[userId];
      if (fetchStatus === 'loading') {
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: I import the `users.slice.ts` inside `store.ts` file. If I import the `RootState` from 'store.ts' inside `users.slice.ts` file.  Will it cause a circular reference?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I am honestly not sure, will have to check but it is the recommended way from the documentations

Comment: @slideshowp2 and I have never faced that issue when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the approach used in [`@types/react-redux`](https://unpkg.com/@types/react-redux@7.1.18/index.d.ts) for [defining a typed alias](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks) of the `useSelector` hook (`TypedUseSelectorHook`) can be used in this case too:

```
type TypedCreateAsyncThunk<ThunkApiConfig> = <Returned, ThunkArg = void>(
  typePrefix: string,
  payloadCreator: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>,
  options?: AsyncThunkOptions<ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>
) => AsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>;

export const createAppAsyncThunk: TypedCreateAsyncThunk<{
  state: RootState;
}> = createAsyncThunk;
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid circular dependencies, how about something like this?

Instead of

```js
createAsyncThunk<User, string>
```

Use

```js
createAsyncThunk<User, string, {state: {users: UserSliceState}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers, the following works fine in my case:

We passed into `createAsyncThunk` these type variables:

1. `type-for-result`: type for the returned when the action is fulfilled (see `try` block)
2. `type-for-data`: type for the second argument's first param of `createAsyncThunk` function
3. `ThunkApiConfig`: here because we require another state's information, we need to tell Typescript the state is the `RootState`, so that we can get the info with `getState()`.  Besides, we can also add `type-for-message` for the message returned when the action is rejected (see `catch` block).

```
export const method = createAsyncThunk<
  type-for-result,
  type-for-data,
  { state: RootState, rejectValue: type-for-message }
>(
  'name',
  async (data, thunk) => { 
    try {
      const something = thunk.getState().someState.someProperty;
      // do something
      return result;
     } catch (error) {
      // do something
      return thunk.rejectWithValue(message);
     }
  })
```

`package.json`:

```
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "6.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Answer (score 1):

What I find best for typescript type inference is to do this:

```
// Import your RootState type from your "store.ts"
import { RootState } from "./store.ts";
...
export const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    ...
  },
  {
    condition: (userId, { getState }) => {
      const { users } = getState() as RootState;
      ...
    },
  }
);
```

Because the type is unknown it [should conform to what type you assert it to be](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).